# How to answer a CLI question using exec from child_process in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I have a problem where I run a script in NodeJs, in this script I have an exec function which calls a CLI program, that CLI program requires two other answers after that command, but I don't know how I can answer this when I exec this from `child_process` so the command will be forever waiting for these answers.

Here is an example, just keep in mind where I have the command `npm init`, it will be the CLI program I am using instead, I know with `npm` I could pass some flag like `-y` and it will work for the answers, but I don't have this feature in the CLI program:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const execFunction = promisify(exec);

const { stdout } = await execFunction(`npm init`);

console.log('stdout', stdout);
```